# How to expose named property provided by module in a component

Tags: android, dependency-injection, retrofit2, dagger-2, okhttp

I've tried to google around my problem, but still don't have an idea about what am I doing wrong.

**The case:** There is a `NetworkModule`, which provides all necessary pieces to build a `Retrofit` object (it is also provided).
One of such a pieces is an `Interceptor` of `OkHttpClient`, where HTTP headers for all requests are set.
Until app's user is not authorized I don't want to do anything with this particular `Interceptor`, but once app receives an `access_token`, I would like to set it into the `Interceptor`, to make it set one more header with this particular `access_token`.

Answers of google are said that a proper way to do it is to expose this `Interceptor` to be able to set this `access_token` when I need to.
So what I did:

Here is my AppComponent:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = [
    AppModule::class,
    DataModule::class,
    NetworkModule::class,
    NetworkServicesModule::class,
    RepositoryModule::class,
    SchedulersModule::class])
interface AppComponent{
    /*
    ...
    */

    @Named(NetworkModule.Interceptors.HEADER)
    val headerInterceptor: Interceptor
}
```

And here is a module, which provides this particular Interceptor:

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {
    object Interceptors {
        const val HEADER = "HTTP_HEADER_INTERCEPTOR"
        ...
    }
    ...
    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    @Named(Interceptors.HEADER)
    fun provideHeaderInterceptor(): Interceptor {
        return HeaderInterceptor()
    }
    ...
}
```

But there is a problem while I try to make my "app" module (Build -> Make module 'app').
While making it, an error occurs and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is how error looks like:

```
error: okhttp3.Interceptor cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract okhttp3.Interceptor getHeaderInterceptor();
okhttp3.Interceptor is provided at
com.example.app.di.components.AppComponent.getHeaderInterceptor()
```

Comment: you used dagger 2 for code.

Comment: @AndroidTeam yes, I'm using Dagger2

Comment: if you want then provide full retrofit demo using dagger 2.

Comment: @AndroidTeam I'm not sure that I follow you. What's the idea of posting demo? The problem is on the surface :) Everything besides that is ok

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs beccause you annotate your field (`val`) instead of the provision method (`getHeaderInterceptor`) which Dagger wants to use.

You can (should) properly declare a provision method:

```
@Named(NetworkModule.Interceptors.HEADER)
fun provideHeaderInterceptor(): Interceptor
```

---

*I don't know how or why you'd use a `val headerInterceptor`, but you can also fix it by declaring the annotation to be used on the getter*

```
@get:Named(NetworkModule.Interceptors.HEADER")
val foo : Any
```